# How to Exclude selection and all related (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, selection

I am trying to solve a mysteries code that writing a number in a choice I will get all opposite of that number
 I did almost done with that the only problem with it I might have the opposite recalled as he does have another recorded in another course
In more word my PHP about courses when I do ask MY PHP course it well give me all people how did not take course 1 but some people were recalled as they have other courses

The Problem when I choose For Example Course X I do get All Who Did not Take Course X But Some where Called From The same Table cause They Do Have Taken Other Courses In the same table

I did resolve The first Problem Using the following code

```
if(isset($_GET['course_guid']) && $_GET['course_guid']!="" )
    $f.=" AND s.course_guid != '".$_GET['course_guid']."'";
```

And I Did Create Another page Select.php To Omit All Identified People from Orig.php using The Following Code

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET['id']))
    foreach($_GET as $key => $post)
        $_GET[$key]=m($post);
$ff="";

if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!="") 
    $ff.=" AND cs.id = '".$_GET['id']."' ";

$prns =(isset($_GET['prn'])? $_GET['prn']:'');
if(isset($prns) && $prns!="")
    $ff.=" AND cs.prn = '".$prns."' ";

$course_guids =(isset($_GET['course_guid'])? $_GET['course_guid']:'');
if(isset($course_guids) && $course_guids!="")
    $ff.=" AND cs.course_guid = '".$course_guids."' ";


    $from_time=system_time();
    $date_from= date("d",$from_time)."-".date("m",$from_time)."-".date("Y",$from_time);
    $date_to=date("d",system_time())."-".date("m",system_time())."-".date("Y",system_time());
if(isset($_GET['alldates']) && $_GET['alldates']=="on") {
    $t_f=mktime(0,0,0,6,1,2011);
    $t_t=system_time();
} else {
    $t_f=mktime(0,0,0,substr($date_from,3,2),substr($date_from,0,2),substr($date_from,6,4));
    $t_t=mktime(23,59,59,substr($date_to,3,2),substr($date_to,0,2),substr($date_to,6,4));
}

$query="SELECT cs.id,cs.prn,cs.course_guid FROM courses_attend cs

    WHERE  cs.time BETWEEN $t_f AND $t_t

$ff

";

//echo "$prns";
$rs22 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

//      $total22 = mysql_num_rows($rs22); 
/*
while($row22=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs22))
{
$prnss =(isset($row22['prn'])? $row22['prn']:'');
    print($prnss); 
}
*/
?>
```

print($prnss); // this should be the code needed to be recalled In Orig.php
and It should Be Called Inside a loop mysql_fetch_array which is cannot be Used In orig.php Cause I do already Have a structure and Another Loop In that page Cause real Output Interface is there
as far as I do know I do think function callback() would be a solve on the other hand I do not know how to create one

Comment: problem is not clear

Comment: can you show your code where the issue is?

Comment: The Problem when I choose For Example Course X i do get All Who Didi not Take Course X But Some where Called From The same Table cause They Do Have Taken Other Courses In the same table

Comment: please update  your   question adding a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: as far as I do know I do think function callback() would be a solve on the other hand I do not know how to create one

Answer (score 0):

// Answer

```
for ($i= 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($rs22);$i++) {
    $row22 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs22); 
        $prnss = $row22['prn'];
    //  echo  "$prnss"; // return print all Omitted data
    //  echo "<br />\n";
    $f.=" AND s.prn != '".$prnss."' ";
    }
```

Solved By Adding This In Orig.php

On the other hand and after testing Select.php DATA can be added TO the Orig.php

Best regards